# Indexing Numpy arrays with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question is a little more abstract than finding the solution with actual code. I am trying to understand some code for some software I am working with. Specifically, I am working with a 4D numpy array which is indexed by 3 other 3D arrays. I've read the following page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html however it does not really cover the complexity of what I am dealing with (or I do not understand it fully to apply it to my situation).

My ultimate goal is to convert this code into C code, and so I need to understand how these arrays are accessed so that I may convert it. Does anyone know any tricks or tips to reading these numpy arrays with 3D array indexing? Is there some procedure I can follow to reconstruct a numpy array in C?

Any help would be appreciated!

For reference the following is what I am dealing with:

`state = history[delays, var, node, :]`

`history.shape = (4192, 2, 74, 1)`

`delays.shape = (74,1,74)`

`var.shape = (74,1,74)`

`node.shape = (74,1,74)`

The node matrix is actually just 
`[[[ 0 0 0... 00]] [[ 1 1 1 ... 1 1]] [[ 2 2 2 ... 2 2]] ... [[73 73 73 ... 73 73 ]]]`
The var matrix is all 0's.
The delays matrix is all integers of various values all modulus 4192.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resulting array will have shape `(74, 1, 74, 1)`. It would be interesting to see the content of your `delays` array: does it really have 5476 different values, or is it just 74 different values repeated 74 times? I ask, because that is actually what is happening with `var` and `node`.

If they are all different, an unoptimized C version of that same indexing would be something like this:

```
float history[4192][2][74][1], state[74][1][74][1];
int delays[74][1][74];

for (int j = 0; j < 74; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 74; k++) {
        state[j][k] = history[delays[j][0][k]][0][k][0];
    }
}
```

If `delays` is not really a 2D array, but a 1D array repeated 74 times side by side, i.e. if `np.all(np.equal.reduce(delays, axis=1))` returns `True`, then you can simplify the above code as follows:

```
float history[4192][2][74][1], state[74][1][74][1];
int delays[74]; /* keep only the unique values */

for (int j = 0; j < 74; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 74; k++) {
        state[j][k] = history[delays[j]][0][k][0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say I have a 4x4x4x4 numpy array 'a'. Then:

```
repr(a).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}').replace('\n', '')
```

prints out an array ready for consumption in C.

```
double a[4][4][4][4] = {{{{  6.92719862e-01,   2.76015214e-01,   7.01148124e-01,            2.56710822e-01}, .......
```

Indexing will have the same coordinates in both, so `a[(0,1,2,3)]` in python will be the same as `a[0][1][2][3]` in C (and in fact you can use the latter syntax in both).

Comment: That's great for transferring the array over if it were static (which does help me in another case), however I want to actually transfer that line of code over to C. I already have history[][][][] constructed in C, but I am not sure how to access it because I am having trouble reading how numpy is used.

Comment: Can you give an example of the array you are using to index into your 4d array?

Comment: I've edited the original question to include what the arrays look like. Thanks :)

Comment: I know what the arrays look like, I'm asking what kind of indexing you're trying to do. Numpy can do some fairly advanced indexing that would be relatively painful to do in C. `a[:, 1:3, :, 3:1:-1]`, for instance. But you can write out a for-loop that iterates over those elements and puts them into a `4x2x4x2` array, so this can still be done in C. Replicating numpy proper is a pretty serious undertaking, and I'd be surprised if it were much faster than numpy.

Comment: This is the indexing:
state = history[delays, var, node, :]

I'm not really sure what you are asking beyond that. I am moving this python code to System C which in turn will be used for synthesis on FPGA hardware. The goal is to speed this up in hardware, but first model it in C (due to the capabilities of System C).